# api working in browser but not in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating a currency converter, i am fetching current currency rate from internet, its fetching values properly on browser but not working on android phone.
 I searched a lot on the internet but i not found suitable and working solution of this problem.

Please help

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script src="../cordova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

<script>

var audv;
var inrv;
var jpyv;
var rubv;
var gbpv;

$.ajax({

    url: 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/AUD.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

            audv = parseFloat(response.rate).toFixed(2);

        }
    }
});

$.ajax({

    url: 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/INR.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

            inrv = parseFloat(response.rate).toFixed(2);

        } 
        else {
        alert('error response : '+response);
        }


    }
});

$.ajax({

    url: 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/JPY.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

            jpyv = parseFloat(response.rate).toFixed(2);

        }
    }
});

$.ajax({

    url: 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/RUB.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

            rubv = parseFloat(response.rate).toFixed(2);

        }
    }
});

$.ajax({

    url: 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/GBP.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

            gbpv = parseFloat(response.rate).toFixed(2);

        }
    }
});

function setValuesInTextFileds(){
document.getElementById('aud').value= audv;
document.getElementById('inr').value= inrv;
document.getElementById('jpy').value= jpyv;
document.getElementById('rub').value= rubv;
document.getElementById('gbp').value= gbpv;
}


$.mobile.loading().hide();

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='MasterContainer'>
<div id='HeaderDiv'>
<div style='float: left;'>
<a href='#' data-rel="back"><img src='../res/icon/Arrows-Back-icon.png' border='0' style='margin-top: 9px;' /></a></div><br/>
<label style='font-size: 20; margin:0 auto;  display:table; vertical-align:middle;'>Show Rates</label>
</div><!-- HeaderDiv ends -->
<table border='0' class='tableclass'>
<col width='30%'>
<col width='30%'>
<col width='30%'>
<tr><th>Country Name</th><th>Currency Name</th><th>Value against USD</th></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>Australia</td><td align='center'>AUD</td><td><input type='number' name='aud' id='aud' class='enjoy-input textfieldclass' style='background: #E8E8E8; padding-left: 5px;' disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>India</td><td align='center'>INR</td><td><input type='number' name='inr' id='inr' class='enjoy-input textfieldclass' style='background: #E8E8E8; padding-left: 5px;' disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>Japan</td><td align='center'>JPY</td><td><input type='number' name='jpy' id='jpy' class='enjoy-input textfieldclass' style='background: #E8E8E8; padding-left: 5px;' disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>Russia</td><td align='center'>RUB</td><td><input type='number' name='rub' id='rub' class='enjoy-input textfieldclass' style='background: #E8E8E8; padding-left: 5px;' disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>UK</td><td align='center'>GBP</td><td><input type='number' name='gbp' id='gbp' class='enjoy-input textfieldclass' style='background: #E8E8E8; padding-left: 5px;' disabled></td></tr>
</table>
<table border='0' class='tableclass'>
<col width='30%'>
<col width='30%'>
<tr><td align='center'>
<div class='button' onclick='setValuesInTextFileds()' style='padding: 10px 20px;'>Get Online</div>
</td><td align='center'>
<div class='button' onclick='setLocalValues()' style='padding: 10px 20px;'>Get Saved</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div><!-- MasterContainer div ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you create manifest file witch for example Internet access? :)

Comment: when i am installing it on device, it asks for full internet access.

Comment: i added <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>  <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />, but its not working, pleae help, asterik sign is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your mobile device to talk to other websites you have to *whitelist them* . If you don't do this then your mobile app cannot communicate with the outside world. (Whitelisting is no needed when you testing on the browser but is always needed when you test on the mobile device).

To whitelist a website you have to one:

1. Modify your `config.xml` to include the line `<access origin="*" />`
2. Install the whitelist plugin either via phonegap build or locally as a cordova plugin. The cordova plugin is found [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

More info on this issue  is found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).

This is a common mistake made by Phonegap Developers. [This](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) articles lists a few more you may be making.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust your Content Security Policy meta tag in the head of your index.html to look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src https://currency-api.appspot.com">
```

Note I added a "connect-src" clause.

This will then permit access to the server you are trying to query for exchange rate data.

A blog post discussing this, which also uses a currency conversion example, can be found [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

Comment: bro, i tried it too, its not working, i uploaded my file in my question

Comment: I don't see any connect-src clause in yours.  Check out the example I posted and put that verbatim in your index.html <head>.  I also notice you are running JS before the Cordova/PhoneGap device ready so I would suggest moving your script to run in the deviceready event handler that you should add.  Check the structure of the similar app in the blog post I linked to.